# Clicking on a date from a calendar using protractor with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, protractor

With the below code I tried to click the specific date in the calendar using protractor but it is not working, so can anybody please help me with how to use calendar selection in protractor using JavaScript. I am new for protractor automation.

```
clickDateByText = function(tileText) {

  //Select all date elements and apply filter function
  element.all(by.xpath(by.xpath("//table[@class='mat-calendar-table']//tr//div"))).filter(function(elem) {

    //Return the element or elements
    return elem.getText().then(function(text) {

      //Match the text
      return text === tileText;
    });

  }).then(function(filteredElements) {

    //filteredElements is the list of filtered elements
    filteredElements[0].click();
  });
};

// Calling..

clickDateByText('28');
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaCvQ.png)

Comment: Please show the calendar HTML code in your question and post a screenshot of your calendar too

Comment: Take care in spelling JavaScript to avoid search collision with Java.